# Can CM11 be installed on a Samsung GS3 that's running 4.4.2?

Tags: samsung, cyanogenmod

I'm trying to change to Cynaogenmod CM11 nightly on my Samsung GS3 but I'm receiving the error assert failed: getprop("ro.bootloader") not matching

I know this normally means you have the older bootloader but if I understand correctly after checking at the shell I'm running I747UCUFNE4 Samsung GS3 Android 4.4.2.

This is the latest bootloader isn't it? Can I not go over to CM11 nightly?

I have the latest CWM installed and I also tried the lastest TWRP but obviously the package has the check in it. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

So the latest d2lte snapshot build installed successfully. It seemed to be satisfied with the bootloader and modem versions. I am now on CM11 and it looks great on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I gave the install script a look and it seems that it does not check for the bootloader version. It does install or patch the bootloader, and hence no check needed.